# Email Client with Vim Editing

Tags: linux, email, vim

I've been using vim for about 5 years now and have grown quite effective with it, to the point where writing things without vim feels so painfully slow.  Just about everything that I write, I write in vim with the exception of email.  All of my email accounts are google hosted, and right now I just use the Gmail interface.  Is there a good client that I can easily setup so that I can write all my emails in vim (and not just copy paste when I'm done)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/). You can use external editor with that, default is vim. The navigation is all similar to vim too.

Answer (score 7):

Use [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4125/) to make your text boxes (including the GMail plain text compose box) editable in an external editor. Or you can set `$EDITOR` to `vim` and use [`alpine`](http://www.washington.edu/alpine/).

Comment: Very regrettably, this plugin has died, as indicated here: https://github.com/docwhat/itsalltext/blob/master/README.md :-(

Answer (score 2):

I know the question was posted almost six years ago, but for anyone else who in the future might land here while trying to figure out how to get vim into every aspect of their lives, I recommend checking out the [wasavi extension](http://appsweets.net/wasavi/). Essentially, Ctrl-Enter will start a vi buffer within the textbox your cursor is currently in. Do all your vi magic and hit ZZ and you're done!

Works in Gmail (which was my primary use case when looking around for something like this, hence why I ended up here). In fact, this answer was typed using vi from within the textbox. Hopefully wasavi will meet your needs. I know I am absolutely loving it.

Comment: Added note: https://github.com/brookhong/Surfingkeys and https://github.com/glacambre/firenvim also do this now.

Answer (score 1):

Any command line email client will let you use your preferred command line editor. The common ones are:

- [mutt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutt_(e-mail_client))
- [alpine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_(e-mail_client)) (formerly known as pine)

Personally I've been loving [sup](http://sup.rubyforge.org/) recently. It's kind of a cross between mutt and gmail. It does tags and search really well, and I increasingly love the whole model of how it works.

Comment: The only problem with sup is that it does not synchronize with Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [ViewSourceWith](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/394/) Firefox plugin for this. Type Ctrl+Shift+U to use `gvim` to edit the text currently in the text box and just exit `gvim` (`ZZ` or `:wq`) to put your edited text back in the text box.